# Code blocks are hard to read on Meta.

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

The gray background is very close to the `code block gray background`. The monospace helps, but when working with individual characters it can get very difficult to notice which are in a code block and which are not. Is it possible to get more of a contrast between the colors?

Comment: Or maybe a border? But I'm sure a real programmer would only change the colour and ignore the border :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have darkened the background some, the change will be in the next production build.

Comment: Oh, yeah, that helps a lot! Thanks!